# Cannot connect to TFS

Tags: tfs

Hi for some reason I cannot connect to TFS anymore.When I try to do that from both te browser and Visual Studio it freezez and I get this error:

[image]

TFS is installed localy on my computer and I am using the defaultCollection and user from windows.

I have been using TFS locally for only a month and everything worked perfectly so far.

I have also tryed reseting my PC and uninstalling and reinstalling TFS but it seemes to have no effect.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Have you Googled the error number? Try: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613214/TF400324-Team-Foundation-services-are-not-availabl

Comment: Have you changed anything with the firewall on your machine, stopped IIS or installed something that hijacked port 8080? Also, have you tried accessing it via 'localhost' instead of your machine name?

Comment: If neither of these help, did you install TFS under a trial (and has the trial now expired)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the TFS Server. Make sure the app pool and site are running. Also if you have VS on the TFS Server (you should for this very reason) try connecting from there. If that works, it could be a network issue.